# Chef windows_share resource path required

Tags: windows, chef-infra, windows-server-2016

windows cookbook version 3.1.1
chef client 13.2.20

Trying to create a window share on server 2016 with the following code.

```
include_recipe "windows"

directory 'c:\share' do
    rights :full_control, "Administrators"
    action :create
end

windows_share "share" do
    action :create
    path 'c:\share'
    full_users ["Administrators"]
end
```

Chef creates the folder ok, but returns the following output on creation of the share:

```
Error executing action `create` on resource 'windows_share[share]'
=========================================================
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
----------------------------------
path is required
```

I clear have path set.  Any ideas on why this would fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting from windows 3.1.1 to windows 3.1.0 has addressed the issue altogether and I'm now able to create shares with windows_share.

Commit fc2691f changed the property to required instead of raising an exception that it was missing.

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows/issues/482

Answer (score 0):

You should use `'c:\\share'`. Backslash is an escape character in strings.

Comment: I thought that depended on whether ' or " were used.  I've tried these: 
 'c:\\share', "c:\\share", 'c:\share', 'c:\\share", 'c:/share', "c:/share", as I've seen it in some of the github items for it.  I don't necessarily think it's this string as it doesn't seem like it's seeing path at all by the error message.